# Way where $K$ elements (numbered $1$ to $K$) can be aligned in $N$ places where only one element is allowed to repeat?

Tags: permutations, combinations

I was asked this question while I was giving an interview for a software engineer role but simply couldn't find the correct answer. I am pretty sure this can be solved using permutation and combination but still always arrived at the wrong answer. Any help would be appreciated.

> What are the number of ways in which, $K$ elements which are numbered from $1$ to $K$ like $1,2,....,K$ can be aligned in $N$ places such that no $2$ same number are adjacent except the one specified as variable $X$ ?

---

For the context of the question, please consider the following example:

$$N = 3 K = 2 X = 1$$

Explanation: Arrange $K = 2$ so $1,2$ in $3$ places such that $2$ cannot be placed next to each other but $1$ can like $1,1$ but not $2,2$.

Possible ways: $\{1,1,1\} , \{1,1,2\} , \{1,2,1\} , \{2,1,1\} , \{2,1,2\}$.

Another example can be:

$$N = 5 K = 4 X = 3$$ And there are $469$ possible ways in total.

---

So, how do I generate a common formula for greater numbers?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this question, we start by building two sequences, $a_n,b_n$ such that $a_n$ is the number of allowed sequences of length $n$ and $b_n$ is the number of allowed sequences of length $n$ assuming that you can't start with one of the regular numbers (i.e. can't start with some specific number that's not $X$).

We are therefore interested in a formula for $a_n$.

Then $a_n = a_{n-1} + (k-1)b_{n-1}$ as we can either choose $X$ as the first number (and then there are $a_{n-1}$ options to continue the sequence) or one of the other $k-1$ options (and then there are $b_{n-1}$ options to continue the sequence for each of the choices).

Quite similarly, we get $b_n = a_{n-1}+(k-2)b_{n-1}$ as we can either choose $X$ or any of the other $k-2$ elements to start the sequence.

We can therefore obtain a matrix equality given by
$$\left[ \array{1\ k-1\newline1\ k-2} \right]\cdot\left[ \array{a_{n-1}\newline b_{n-1}} \right]=\left[ \array{a_{n}\newline b_{n}} \right]$$

After finding $a_1=k,b_1=k-1$, we could calculate the $n$'th element of $a$ by diagonalising the matrix above (it has 2 eigenvalues for every real, positive value of $k$, thus is diagonalisable for such values), and, denoting by $P$ the change of basis matrix and $D$ the diagonal matrix, taking this form to the $n$'th power, then calculating $PD^{n-1}P^{-1}\left[ \array{a_{1}\newline b_{1}} \right]$, or if you rather, since $\left[ \array{1\ k-1\newline1\ k-2} \right]\left[ \array{1\newline 1} \right]=\left[ \array{a_{1}\newline b_{1}} \right]$, one could calculate $$PD^{n}P^{-1}\left[ \array{1\newline 1} \right]$$ and return the first coordinate.

There might be an easier way to do this, but unfortunately I couldn't find one :)